# 'Invalid parameter type. param-index=1 param-type=method', 'HY105' - Python error while inserting to MS SQL table

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I am trying to insert a dataframe loaded from an API into MS SQL database server.
Connection to the database was established successfully, but insertion is failing. Please find my code below

```
def insert(db_connect):
try:
    cursor = db_connect.cursor()
    sql_query = cursor.execute("Select * from Dashboard")
    allrows = sql_query.fetchall()
    totalrows = len(allrows)
    if totalrows > 0:
        cursor.execute("Truncate table Dashboard")
        logging.info('Truncated table :  ' + today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M"))     
        
    text_data = response.text        
    json_dict = json.loads(text_data)        
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_dict["elements"])
    
    print(df.columns.to_list())     
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Dashboard (SKID,Item,IDate,Warehouse,Location,TDate,Stock,GRN,Lane,Company) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.mnum, row.item, row.idat, row.cwar, row.loca, row.trdt, row.stks, row.cval, row.valu1_0, row.company)
        
    logging.info('Data inserted successfully :  ' + today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M"))
    #os.getcwd()
    ArchiveFilePath = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'Archive\\Dashboard_'+ d1 +'.xlsx')
    column_names = ['Mnum', 'Item','Idat','Cwar', 'Loca', 'Trdt', 'Stks', 'Cval', 'Valu 1', 'Company']
    df.to_csv(ArchiveFilePath,index=False,header=column_names, columns=['mnum','item','idat', 'cwar','loca','trdt', 'stks', 'cval', 'valu1', 'company' ])
    logging.info('File Created Successfully :  ' + today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H-%M"))    
except Exception as e:
    print('Could not insert to database')
    logging.info('Could not insert to database :  ' + {str(e)})
```

But i am getting the below error

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1
> param-type=method', 'HY105')

my sql table design is as shown below.

[image]

**************************** Edited **********************************

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\tjohn\Desktop\Teena\Dashboard\dashboard.py", line 88, in insert
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Dashboard (SKID,Item,InvDate,Warehouse,Location,TransactionDate,Stock,GRN,Lane,Cane,Company) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.mnum, row.item, row.idat, row.cwar, row.loca, row.trdt, row.stks.cvalompany) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", row.mnum, row.item, row.idat, row.cwar, row.loca, row, row.cval, row.valu1_0, row.company)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=method', 'HY105')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\tjohn\Desktop\Teena\Dashboard\dashboard.py", line 108, in 
insert(db_connect)
File "c:\Users\tjohn\Desktop\Teena\Dashboard\dashboard.py", line 98, in insert
logging.info('Could not insert to database :  ' + {str(e)})
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

---

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,
Teena

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? at what line are you getting the error

Comment: Why not just use [to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)?

Comment: @darth baba , Hi I have added the stacktrace. Please do check.